# Error: Cannot find module. at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem.

I watched the course on creating a Telegram bot, I did everything as in the video, but when I start it, it gives me an error. There are no errors in the code, I don’t know what the problem is.

Here's the code itself:

```js
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf('SECRET_API_KEY');

//          /start
bot.start((ctx) => {
    ctx.reply("You have entered the start command");
})

bot.Launch();
```

Comment: `bot.launch()` instead of `bot.Launch()`

Answer (score 1):

The method on bot is `launch` with a small 'L', i.e. `bot.launch()`

Also, please don't expose your API Key like that